# Select using a php variable with more than one ID

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP variable that looks like this for example:

```
$list = "12|421|466|501|1042|"
```

What I wanna do is to match each number with a field in my database table.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = any of the numbers in $list
```

Which is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use replace to replace | into comma and remove the last |  so that you could get the string in 

correct format

```
$list = str_replace('|',',',$list);
$query = "select * from table where ID in ($list)";
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (12, 431, 466, 501, 1042)
```

Use [explode()](http://php.net/explode), [implode()](http://php.net/implode) to convert your list to a comma separated list.

Answer (score 2):

Use IN like this:

`"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (".str_replace('|', ',', substr($list, 0, -1)).")"`

Comment: I think this would yield a parse error, as the last char in $list is a |, so the SQL would contain IN( x, y, z, ). Note the last comma. I think filtering would help here, as per my example.

Comment: Yes - the trailing comma gives a MySQL error. Edited to remove last character from $list

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%$list%'
```

not so sure | is a good seperator. maybe u should try setting it into an array.

guy below got it!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$list = "12|421|466|501|1042|";
$items = array_filter( 
     array_map( 'trim', explode( "|", $list ) ),
     function( $item ) {
         return $item != ''; // filter empty values.
     }
);
$query = 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id IN ( ' . implode( ', ', $items ) . ' );';
echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wan the combined result you can use `IN` statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN ( $cat = str_replace("|", "," , $list) )
```

Or if you want the separate results you have to iterate through all the values.

```
$array = preg_split( "\\|" , $list );
foreach ($array as $value) {
    SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN ('.str_replace('|',',',$list).');

it will repalce all | with , and then you can run query with IN condition to get desired records..